# How to pass a variable to a twig block in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I am displaying a date time widget in a web page I am developing. By default time part only show hours and minutes. I need to show seconds too.

I have found that the date time wtdget has a variable called with_seconds, but I need to pass true from the form.

This is what I have but it did not work:

```
{{ form_widget(edit_form.fechhoramarcada, { 'attr': {'class': 'input-text no-border'}, 'with_seconds': true }) }}
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change default options when you creating them.

```
$builder->add('fechhoramarcada', 'datetime', array(
    'with_seconds'    => true,
));
```